# Oracle Storage Full, How to release space?

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, aws, storage

i have and **AWS RDS Oracle Database** wich its storage is full, looks like the cause is SYSAUX tablespace with 10.2GB size

The largest object inside SYSAUX is: WRI$_ADV_OBJECTS (TABLE) checking the table data looks like **"Optimizer Statistics Advisor Task"** Data is taking  9GB.

How can i delete this data and release the storage? and
How can i stoped this Task to generate so much information and consuming all my free space?

(Notes: this database was created as 11G instance couple of years ago and was updated to 19 recently)

*I've tried these **2** approaches (connected with the master user):*

**1) RUN AWS PACKAGES**
To stop the "Optimizer Statistics Advisor" task and also to keep the task info for only 5 days (instead of the 30 days default period)

RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL.ADVISOR_TASK_DROP('AUTO_STATS_ADVISOR_TASK');
RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL.ADVISOR_TASK_SET_PARAMETER('AUTO_STATS_ADVISOR_TASK', 'DAYS_TO_EXPIRE', '5' );
RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL.ADVISOR_TASK_SET_PARAMETER('AUTO_STATS_ADVISOR_TASK', 'EXECUTION_DAYS_TO_EXPIRE', '5' );

But i only get error messages for all of them:
PLS-00302: component 'ADVISOR_TASK_DROP' must be declared
PLS-00302: component 'ADVISOR_TASK_SET_PARAMETER' must be declared

**2) TRUNCATIN WRI$_ADV_OBJECTS TABLE**
with the command TRUNCATE TABLE SYS.WRI$_ADV_OBJECTS DROP STORAGE

but i get this error:
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RDSADMIN.RDS_DDL_TRIGGER2'

Comment: Did your search on the internets led you to [this](https://dbpilot.net/2021/sysaux-tablespace-is-too-large-because-of-optimizer-statistics-advisor-task-data/)?

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for your help, yes i found that page and tried the procedure, and i think it would work on a normal installation of oracle, but im talking about oracle on the cloud with AWS.. so those procedures are disabled and they provide their own